# Website gets slow when cron job is executing

Tags: cron, slowdown, database-connection

I have a website that is live. I have a **cron job that executes every 24 hours**. the cron job fetches and analyzes the data from a database table.
The problem is that the **website gets very slow during the time when cron job is running.** And gets back to normal after that. It **gives me error Too many connections during this time**.[image]
I set the **maximum allowed connections to 500 in mysql.** The number of active connections that I checked in mysql were **less than limit during that time.**
[image]
I am unable to find any relevant help or even a clue to think in a particular direction.
**Update:**
I noticed one thing. the number of mysql connection continuously increases in this time. Although still less than the maximum limit.

Answer (score 0):

`nice` command can change priority of a process. You want to lower the priority of the background process so it will try not to <strike>execute</strike> be executing while the website is being busy. E.g.

```
0 3 * * *      nice -n 20 myjob arg arg
```

to execute `myjob arg arg` with lowered priority every day at 3am.

EDIT: Although, if the job is spending most of its time in database queries, this will not affect it much. MySQL has `LOW_PRIORITY` flag for `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements that will do kind of the same thing for those queries.

Comment: I don't want it to get delayed. The cron job is required to run every 24 hour.

Comment: I might have worded that wrong. It would not be delayed; it would be _started_ on time, but its scheduling would be affected so that it would be less likely to be switched to if other, higher-priority processes are making CPU busy. Imagine a guy reading Reddit at work; when there's work they work, when there's no work they continue reading Reddit.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Let me try this. I will update you in next 24 hour. As it will execute agian tomorrow